# Are there any performance benefits in C# discards?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Consider this code:

```
var (mult, sum) = MultSum(a, b);
```

and

```
var (_, sum) = MultSum(a, b);
```

**Question 1.**
If I use discard instead of a variable name, does it have performance benefit? eg. by reducing assignment operations.

**Question 2.**
Is there any way to write the `MultSum` smart enough so it doesn't calculate the discards!?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards *"Because there is only a single discard variable, and that variable may not even be allocated storage, discards can reduce memory allocations. Because they make the intent of your code clear, they enhance its readability and maintainability."*

Comment: 1) I seriously doubt it 2) Write separate Sum and Mult methods and only call the one you need.

Comment: @juharr 1) Seems it reduces memory allocations due to Herohtar comment. 2) It's just an example to describe my idea.

Comment: I find that assertion to be specious, or at the very least, in need of clarification... If a method returns a reference and you discard it, it still allocated the instance and returned it. You're not changing the method to not allocate it just because you don't want it.

Comment: @madreflection Note that it says "*can* reduce". There won't be additional allocations on the calling side of the code, because the value isn't actually assigned to anything in the case of a discard. *"`_` is not assigned a value, and may not even be assigned a storage location."*

Comment: To clarify I doubt it will be a precieveable difference.  And you would have to let the method know what to do by passing something to it.  It cannot figure out what you do with what it returns.

Comment: The second question makes me think that you're possibly asking an "XY" question. That is, you have some real problem, you have some bizarre solution in mind to that real problem, and now you're asking a question about that solution rather than asking a question about the real problem. What is the real problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: What @EricLippert said -- In 95% of the performance questions I've seen on StackOverflow, the performance impact wasn't worth worrying about. If you want to optimize code for some purpose, try pasting the code you want to optimize.

Comment: @EricLippert In fact I haven't any real problem out there! I just was curious about the second question, which made me ask the former question first! Now I see it would be better to ask it another way, not mentioning the performance at all!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> If I use discard instead of a variable name, does it have performance benefit? eg. by reducing assignment operations.

In your particular case it is unlikely that there would be a benefit in performance. The tuple that is returned is assigned to temporary storage; you've just not given a name to one part of that storage.

Now, if you had an expression that had discards that were entire values, not fragments of a tuple, then the compiler and the jitter can be smart about not allocating any storage on the short-term pool for the result, or re-using existing storage that was already allocated. Note that by "short-term pool" I effectively mean "activation record on the stack" or "registers".  This could, in theory, lead to better register allocation or smaller frames (and therefore better locality of reference) and that in turn could save you entire *nanoseconds*.

Nano-optimizations are generally not worth it; there is almost always a better bang-for-buck performance problem to attack.  But if you think it might be relevant for your scenario, **measure it and see**. That is the *only* way to know if there is a relevant performance difference.  Get out a nano-scale stopwatch, run the code both ways, and see which one is faster.

The benefit you should be attempting to accrue by using discards is the "make my program easier to understand" benefit. Programmers are expensive; optimize for making your code easy for future programmers to read, understand and modify.

> Is there any way to write the MultSum smart enough so it doesn't calculate the discards!?

Yes. *Write your program in Haskell.*  Haskell will avoid performing calculations whose results are never used.  C# is not such a language.